# removing outline color of scatter plot in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have gridded data with dimensions (x,y) and values are in z.
so simply we can make scatter plot for third dimension by:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)
plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, s=150, cmap = 'jet')
plt.show()
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2acLp.png]

what i am thinking now is to remove the line color of each circular scatter plot. And also instead of circle can we make it square??

I did not find any way to do that. your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Pass the argument `edgecolors='none'` to `plt.scatter`. The patch boundary will not be drawn.
- Pass the argument `marker='s'` to `plt.scatter`. The marker style will be square.

Then, we have,

[image]

---

The source code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)
plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, s=150, cmap = 'jet', edgecolors='none', marker='s')
plt.show()
```

Refer to [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) for more information.

Comment: Also note that in `matplotlib` 2.0.x, the default behaviour is to not plot the edges in scatter plots (and other objects)